# KnockoutJS: Cant access value of observable array using index

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to change the flag value of an item of the complex object.
Object structure is:

```
modelData 
    [0]: 
        Main: xz1
        Sub: a,b,c,d,e
        show: true
    [1]:
        Main: xs1
        Sub: g,h,i,j,k
        show: false
```

I need to access this object and toggle the flag value, if it is true i have to change this as false, if false means i have to make this as true.

Code I tried

```
toggleShow: function (item) {
          var index = modelData.indexOf(item);
          modelData[index].show = item.show ? false : true; // should get work but not :(
}
```

item data inside function is,

```
item
{...}
    __proto__: {...}
    Main: "AXD"
    Sub: [ fg,jk,ik,ko]
    show: true
```

modelData is an observable Array.

```
modelData
function observable() {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            // Write

            // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
            if (observable.isDifferent(_latestValue, arguments[0])) {
                observable.valueWillMutat
    [Methods]: {...}
    __proto__: {...}
    _id: 168
    _latestValue: [[object Object]]
    _subscriptions: {...}
    arguments: null
    caller: null
    length: 0
    prototype: {...}
```

By using that _latestValue i can fetch the object content.

```
modelData._latestValue
[[object Object]]
    __proto__: []
    length: 1
    [0]: {...}
```

but I could not access this using index. Please tell me where my things getting wrong and why i could not access the value using index of the element.

EDIT:

Now I can toggle the flag value. But once the flag value updated my list in view not getting updated. Please find my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MJSuriya/vpndkxgu/1/)
Output:

```
+ Main1
    hello
    hi
+ Main2
    one
    two
```

if I click that plus symbol then sub list should get hide. if i again click that plus symbol it should show the sub list again.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [unwrap your observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#reading-information-from-an-observablearray) to get the underlying array with calling `modelData` as a function with no arguments.

So you need to add the `()` before the `[index]`:

```
toggleShow: function (item) {
          var index = modelData.indexOf(item);
          modelData()[index].show = item.show ? false : true; 
}
```

Note: the [`indexOf` is working](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#indexOf) without the `()` because it is implemented additionally for the observableArray but the indexer is not.

In order to see the changes on the UI you have to convert your `show` property a `ko.observable`, and you need to updated it with:

```
toggleShow: function (item) {
          var index = modelData.indexOf(item);
          modelData()[index].show(item.show() ? false : true); 
}
```

Your updated code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ujs77n7r/

Comment: can we write `modelData()[index].show = !(modelData()[index].show)` to toggle it? I mean is it any better?

Comment: Yes I have checked it. But now, My view is not get updated once i have toggled that flag value. Can you please check my fiddle. I have attached fiddle in question. Thanks much

Comment: @MJSuriya you have to convert your `show` property to a `ko.observable` the see the changes on the UI. In this case you have to write: `modelData()[index].show(item.show() ? false : true);`

Comment: Thats amazing. Thanks Much :)